# pyspark applying odm mapping on column level

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I have below 2 data frames and i would like to apply similar condition and return the values in pyspark data frames.

df1.show()

```
+---+-------+--------+
|id |tr_type|nominal |
+---+-------+--------+
|1  |K      |2.0     |
|2  |ZW     |7.0     |
|3  |V      |12.5    |
|4  |VW     |9.0     |
|5  |CI     |5.0     |
+---+-------+--------+
```

One dimensional mapping:
*abcefgh

```
+-------+------------+------------+-----------+
|odm_id |return_value|odm_relation|input_value|
+-------+------------+------------+-----------+
|abcefgh|B           |EQ          |K          |
|abcefgh|B           |EQ          |ZW         |
|abcefgh|S           |EQ          |V          |
|abcefgh|S           |EQ          |VW         |
|abcefgh|I           |EQ          |CI         |
+-------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

I need to apply below condition The nominal volume is negated when there is a sell transaction.

IF (tr_type, $abcefgh.) == 'S' THEN ;
nominal = -nominal ;

The expected output:

```
+---+-------+-------+-----------+
|id |tr_type|nominal|nominal_new|
+---+-------+-------+-----------+
|1  |K      |2.0    |2.0        |
|2  |ZW     |7.0    |7.0        |
|3  |V      |12.5   |-12.5      |
|4  |VW     |9.0    |-9.0       |
|5  |CI     |5.0    |5.0        |
+---+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could `join` the 2 dataframes on `tr_type == input_value` and use a `when().otherwise()` to create the new column.

see example below using your samples

```py
data_sdf. \
    join(odm_sdf.selectExpr('return_value', 'input_value as tr_type').
         dropDuplicates(), 
         ['tr_type'], 
         'left'
         ). \
    withColumn('nominal_new', 
               func.when(func.col('return_value') == 'S', func.col('nominal') * -1).
               otherwise(func.col('nominal'))
               ). \
    drop('return_value'). \
    show()

# +-------+---+-------+-----------+
# |tr_type| id|nominal|nominal_new|
# +-------+---+-------+-----------+
# |      K|  1|    2.0|        2.0|
# |     CI|  5|    5.0|        5.0|
# |      V|  3|   12.5|      -12.5|
# |     VW|  4|    9.0|       -9.0|
# |     ZW|  2|    7.0|        7.0|
# +-------+---+-------+-----------+
```